# Old drive expired and I'm trying to create a fresh Repo But I'm getting error -"Project not added to Subversion because it is out of working copy"

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I have a project where the repository was on a disk that now is faulty.
so I have created a new repo folder in file explorer on a new disk.
I then deleted the .svn folder in my project as I thought that would make it like a fresh project (obviously I was wrong about that)
as It still wont add the project to the new repo with error "Project not added to Subversion because it is out of working copy"
It doesn't even ask where I want to create the Repo so somehow the project still has the old address.
I also altered my .sln solution file changing Svn-Managed to = False
The Old repo is gone and I'm using a backup that has been altered in the past.
Could anyone help me get round this please

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that your case is unclear and maybe several screenshots and details about your environment will help (solution directories layout, versions of VisualSVN, TortoiseSVN, Visual Studio).

If you want to add your solution into a new repository, run the **Extensions | VisualSVN | Add Solution to Subversion** command and follow the steps of the wizard. If you receive warnings, please examine them and update your question with these details. Note that you need to `svn commit` your solution to publish your solution's data into a repository.

Additional notes:

1. Removing the `.svn` directory from a working copy effectively unties the directory from Subversion. I.e., this action unversions the working copy. Note that up-to-date VisualSVN and Subversion versions place only one `.svn` directory at the root of a working copy. But SVN 1.6 and older have this directory in every folder of a working copy.
2. If you want to re-add an existing solution to a new repository, then indeed you could remove the `.svn` directory or run `svn export` from the working copy into a new directory - this creates an unversioned copy of your working copy. Note that you may need to re-open your Visual Studio solution after removing the `.svn` directory.
3. The command Add Solution to Subversion is only active if the opened solution is not in a working copy (i.e., when it is not versioned). If the command is greyed out, then you need to unversion your solution first. See [TortoiseSVN Manual | Exporting a Subversion working copy](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-export.html#tsvn-dug-export-unversion) (section *Removing a working copy from version control* at the bottom of the page).
4. VisualSVN does not place the `Svn-Managed to = False` string into your solution's .sln file. VisualSVN does not depend on it. I assume that this string was recorded by another Visual Studio plug-in.